# Qt. How correctly print data from QThread object?

Tags: multithreading, qt

I have QList which contains inhereted from QThread objects. These objects in `run()` method do some work in cycle with different periodicity(I use `QThread::sleep`) and results save in private fields.

#### Question

How correct print result in QTableView or QTableWidget?

my idea - create thread that will print in QTableWidget result in infinity cycle, but I guess that this idea is terrible...

```
//httpgettask.h

//Task inherit from QThread
class HttpGetTask : public Task
{
public:
    HttpGetTask(const QString &, const int &, const int &);
    HttpGetTask(const QUrl &, const int &, const int &);
    void run();
};

//httpgettask.cpp

HttpGetTask::HttpGetTask(const QUrl &url, const int &period, const int &errLimit) :
    Task(url, period, errLimit, "HTTP GET")
{
}

HttpGetTask::HttpGetTask(const QString &url, const int &period, const int &errLimit) :
    Task(url, period, errLimit, "HTTP GET")
{
}

void HttpGetTask::run()
{
    TestConn conn(url);
    Response res;
    QString msg;

    int errCount = 0;

    while (!stopThread)
    {
        msg = "";
        res = conn.get();

        if (!res.isSuccess())
        {
            if (++errCount == errLimit) {
                msg = QString("ERROR!! %1 ERROR").arg(errLimit);
                ++errors;
                errCount = 0;
            }
        }

        msg =  QString("%1 %2 %3 %4").arg(QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString(datePattern),
                                          msg,
                                          "HTTP_GET",
                                          res.getMessage());
        writeResultFile(msg);
        ++checkCount;
        QThread::sleep(period);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show some code that outlines the problem -- preferably a [mcve].  The \`traditional' `Qt` way of communicating between threads is via queued signals/slots.

Comment: Okay, i add some code. I guess that each Task must have signal-slot relations between some model from QTableWIdget. If any task update information than model will receive a signal. but in this case task must know his index in list...

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. Just create QTimer and update QTableWidget in timer slot